# Exclude from displaying, when we fetch data from db

Tags: 7, database

My requirement is like: I am retrieving some data from 2 tables of a db,and displaying. Now I want to exclude from displaying,those data which is not present in third table. So how can i achieve this please suggest me. I tried like following code,after this I am not getting.

```
 function viewlist_boatpassengers(){

    if((isset($_COOKIE['viewlistsuccess']) && ($_COOKIE['viewlistsuccess'] == true)) || (user_is_logged_in())) {
      $result = db_select('capcup_boat', 'n')
          ->fields('n', array('boat_id', 'boat_name', 'contact_person_first_name', 'contact_person_initials', 'contact_person_surname'))
        ->execute();
        while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
          $listresult['boats'][] = $record;
        }

      $result = db_select('capcup_passenger', 'n')
          ->fields('n', array('passenger_uid', 'passenger_fname', 'passenger_insertion', 'passenger_lname'))
        ->execute();
        while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
          $listresult['passengers'][] = $record;
        }

      $result = db_select('capcup_boat_to_passenger', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('passenger_uid', 'boat_id'))
        ->execute();
        while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
          $listresult['boatpassengers'][] = $record;
        }

      if(isset($listresult['boatpassengers'][0]['passenger_uid'])){
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($listresult['boatpassengers'][0]['passenger_uid'])  ;exit;

      }
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($listresult)  ;exit;
      $list_page = theme('viewlist_boatpassengers',  array('listresult' => $listresult));  
      return $list_page;
    }
```

If `passanger_uid` is present in the `capcup_boat_to_passenger` table then that data should not displayed.

Comment: Why not use joins? See https://www.drupal.org/node/1848348

Comment: Yes we can,but i am new to DB things, so can you please look into this link and if possible give me solution there..  Thanks inadvance.http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203231/how-to-use-table-join-in-dynamic-query

Comment: `Line #3` from the link is not clear to me. Is `n.passenger_uid` is a list of user id? If what you want is to check if the `cp.passenger_uid` is equal to `n.passenger_uid` then the `line #3` should be `$query->condition('n.passenger_uid','cp.passenger_uid', '=');`

Comment: Out of curiosity what OS are you using. Would be useful if you check your logs to see what is going on when there is error.